# Test a spring boot microservice that needs to call another microservice

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I have followed [this tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4668216-optimisez-votre-architecture-microservices) to create an e-commerce microservice architecure (in french) and now I am trying to write some tests. My architecture is composed of 4 microservices with Eureka and Zuul:

- A product microservice that is here to provide a list of products
- An order microservice that will handle the orders
- A payment microservice that will handle the payments
- A client UI

The payment microservice have to call the orders microservice to check if the order has already been payed or not. And this is what I can't reproduce to write unit tests. I would like to test this microservice without launching the orders microservice.

How can I test it without launching orders microservice?

I already wrote some tests for orders microservice and products microservice.

Here is the payment Controller:

```
/*
*  Operations to save a payment and notify the orders microservice to update the status of the sayed oreder
**/
@PostMapping(value = "/payment")
public ResponseEntity<Payment>  payAnOrder(@RequestBody Payment payment){

    // We verify if the order has been already payed
    System.out.println("We verify if the order has been already payed");
    Payment existingPayment = paymentDao.findByidOrder(payment.getIdOrder());
    if(existingPayment != null) throw new ExistingPaymentException("This order has already been payed!");

    // We save the payment
    System.out.println("We save the payment");
    Payment newPayment = paymentDao.save(payment);

    // if the DAO return null, there was a problem when saving the payment
    System.out.println("if the DAO return null, there was a problem when saving the payment");
    if(newPayment == null) throw new ImpossiblePaymentException("Error, impossible to establish the payment, retry later!");

    // We retrieve the order corresponding to that payment by calling orders microservice
    System.out.println("We retrieve the order corresponding to that payment by calling orders microservice");
    Optional<OrderBean> orderReq = microserviceOrderProxy.retrieveOneOrder(payment.getIdOrder());

    // orderReq.get() extract the object of type OrderBean from Optional
    System.out.println("orderReq.get() extract the object of type OrderBean from Optional");
    OrderBean order = orderReq.get();

    // We update the object to mak the order as payed
    System.out.println("We update the object to mak the order as payed");
    order.setOrderPayed(true);

    // We send the object updated to the orders microservice to update the order's status
    System.out.println("We send the object updated to the orders microservice to update the order's status");
    microserviceOrderProxy.updateOrder(order);

    // We return 201 CREATED to notify the client that the payment has been registered
    System.out.println("We return 201 CREATED to notify the client that the payment has been registered");
    return new ResponseEntity<Payment>(newPayment, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

I am blocked at the step where we retrieve the order corresponding to the payment because it tries to call orders microservice but its not running!

Here is the entire code: https://github.com/kamal951/POC_microservices

Comment: you'll want to look into https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract, its easy to mock service calls but for effective tests you'll nee contract tests

Comment: @kamal951 I have a similar problem to call a method of another service. I hope you can help me. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-another-service-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily mock the other microservices you are calling in your unit test. In Mockito (which is bundled in `spring-boot-starter-test`), you can do this with the following approach:

```
public class PaymentControllerTest {

    private PaymentController controller;

    @Mock
    private MicroserviceOrderProxy microserviceOrderProxy;

    ... other mocks here

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        controller = new PaymentController(microserviceOrderProxy, ...);
    }

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        Mockito.when(microserviceOrderProxy.updateOrder(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(--mocked result here--);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it still fails because it tries to call the orders microservice: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing GET http://localhost:9002/orders/2`

Comment: You need to mock every single service call so it does not get to a real restTemplate call. This was just an example of mocking such service call but you need to apply this approach to all your contracts in the relevant class.

Comment: In the example, in the setUp method, he creates an instance of PaymentController with microserviceOrderProxy in parameter but the controller have no parameters. I don't understand what it does here.

Comment: I recommend switching to constructor injection instead of field injection. You will be able to inject the mock with constructor parameter. If you insist on using field injection, you will probably need to inject the mock using reflection.

Comment: @Smajl I have a similar problem to call a method of another service. I hope you can help me. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-another-service-m