# Spring Boot Microservice - JUnit Controller Test - Cannot call url of another module from one module ( Status 404 ) How to mock microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a problem about running any test of service regarding spring boot microservice.

The **issue** is located at **OrderControllerTest** of order service.

After running all services up, I tried to run any test of **OrderControllerTest** but I got this issue shown below.

I got **Status = 404** as `authenticate/login` belongs to auth service.

I have an **auth service** to implement the process of authentication and authorization with JWT.

Th request url which I want to request is `http://AUTH-SERVICE/authenticate/login`

How can I fix it?

I tried to use some options but they didn't help me fix the issue.

```
JWTResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:7777/authenticate/login", loginRequest, JWTResponse.class);

JWTResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://AUTH-SERVICE:7777/authenticate/login", loginRequest, JWTResponse.class);
```

What should I do?

Here is the test method.

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Place Order -- Success Scenario")
    @WithMockUser(username = "User", authorities = { "ROLE_USER" })
    void test_When_placeOrder_DoPayment_Success() throws Exception {

        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleUser();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeorder")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String orderId = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(orderId));
        assertTrue(order.isPresent());

        Order o = order.get();
        assertEquals(Long.parseLong(orderId), o.getId());
        assertEquals("PLACED", o.getOrderStatus());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getTotalAmount(), o.getAmount());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getQuantity(), o.getQuantity());

    }
```

Here is the getJWTTokenForRoleUser method shown below.

```
private String getJWTTokenForRoleUser() throws Exception {

        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest("User","User");

        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/authenticate/login")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(asJsonString(loginRequest)))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        var loggedUser = objectMapper.readValue(content, JWTResponse.class);

        String jwt = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(loggedUser.getToken());

        return jwt;
    }
```

Here is the **getUserNameFromJwtToken** of JwtUtils in **order service**

```
public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
     if(token.startsWith("Bearer")){
                token = token.substring(7);
     }
     String username= Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
     return username;
}
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

**To run the app,**

1 ) Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)

2 ) Run config server

3 ) Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker

```
  docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
  docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

4 ) Run api gateway

5 ) Run other services

Comment: The repo link is not accesable

Comment: @rostIvan I revised the link. You can access the link now.